# Win 8.1 Metro Hub Navigation

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, navigation, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

In a Hub view App with subItems Pages, my question is when I navigate to a sub item detail Page and then use command navigate goback, the view always returns to pageroot hub section01.

How can I return the MainHub Page to the original calling section that went to the sub page in the first place?

My research has been fruitless. I don't think snaps are my answer but hey any advice is appreciated.

I apologize if this is a very simple question but...

Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Thanks for the answers. After looking at this problem for three days I have found a solution but not quite an answer.

**this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;**

By enabling Navigation Caching the page will return to it's sender position. However I still desire to return to the Hub root page to a specific section. If anyone still has info on how to achieve this I would be grateful.

Seasons Greetings.

Answer (score 2):

Well the newbie here has also discovered the MyHub.**ScrollToSection**(MyHub.Sections[0]);

This allows you to navigate directly to a section thereby bringing it into the current view.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to find an answer to the same question. This is what I've found so far. I welcome any better solutions.

**Option 1**

Enable caching for the page. Note that this must be set in the page constructor or XAML. This will increase memory usage but will improve performance of your app when you navigate back to a cached page.

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
```

More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode.aspx

**Option 2**

Manually save a controls state between page navigations. The example below is using the NavigationHelper class which is added to a new Windows Store project by default.

```
private void OnNavigationHelperSaveState(obj sender, SaveStateEventArgs e)
{
    e.PageState["SelectedSection"] = this.MainHub.SectionsInView;
}

private void OnNavigationHelperLoadState(obj sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)        
{
    if (e.PageState != null)
    {
        var sections = e.PageState["SelectedSection"] as IList<HubSection>;
        if (sections != null && sections.Any())
        {
            this.MainHub.ScrollToSection(sections[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh986968.aspx

Comment: Hi,

using the default Hub Universal App template I added the ScrollToSection in OnNavigationHelperLoadState.

This doesn't work - when I instead add a timer and call the ScrollToSection there it works.
So I guess there is some magic going on after LoadState which scroll the Hub to the start.

Since such a timer is not the best solution - has anyone an idea where (how) to call the scroll correctly?

Answer (score 1):

you could get the Hub's descendant scrollviewer and register to scrollchanged events, store the scrollOffsets and restore them as soon as the user navigates back to the page by applying the values to the hub's scrollviewer.

I guess you would have to register to the hub's loaded event to get the descending scrollviewer (you can use an Extension method from [WinRt XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/) that allows you to get the descendants by Type (e.g. Scrollviewer)

greetings!

Answer (score 1):

you can delete un back stack with this :

```
if(this.Frame.CanGoBack)
{
    this.Frame.BackStack.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried what i suggested?

Unforunately Hub can't be extended to do this and access it's Scrollviewer so you have to do this with an attached Property or plainly in your page.cs .

First you register an handler for the Loaded event of your hub. In the handler you get the descending scrollviewer (with the help of WINRT XAML Toolkit maybe) and register for it's ViewChanged Event.
You store the paremeters you like somewhere they don't get deleted on page navigation and restore and attach them to the scrollviewer on backwards-navigation.

I can give you example code in the afternoon.

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

It's not a ridiculous request. Try this:

```
public static class Concurrency
{
    public static HubSection GotoSection { get; set; }
}

public class MainPage : Page
{
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Concurrency.GotoSection != null)
            MainHub.ScrollToSection(Concurrency.GotoSection);
        Concurrency.GotoSection = null;
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Concurrency.GotoSection = MainHub.SectionsInView.First();
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    }
}
```

The reason `this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;` may not be the correct solution is because you might want your hub to be refreshed. If the detail page resulted in an edit (or especially a delete) a back navigation would show stale data, and subject your app to un unexpected state if the user interacts with dead data.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Enable cache mode on your page at initialization

```
        public MainHubPage()
        {
      .     .......
            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
            .......
        }
```

Comment: check the reason mentioned in [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/21125193/2246380) answer and update your answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Loaded method to Page constructor.

```
MainHub.Loaded += async (s, e) => await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            //here you can scroll
            MainHub.ScrollToSection(Loyaltysection);
        });
```